# how to get webpage resource content via chrome remote debugging

Tags: python, google-chrome, websocket

i want get webpage resource content use python via Chrome Debugging Protocol,from this page [method-getResourceContent](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/Page/#method-getResourceContent),i noticed this method：getResourceContent,need params frameId and url.i think this method is what i need.
so i did this thing:

1.get start chrome as a server: .\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

2.write python test code:

```
# coding=utf-8
"""
chrome --remote-debugging api test
"""

import json
import requests
import websocket

import pdb

def send():
    geturl = requests.get('http://localhost:9222/json')
    websocketURL = json.loads(geturl.content)[0]['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
    request = {}
    request['id'] = 1
    request['method'] = 'Page.navigate'
    request['params'] = {"url": 'http://global.bing.com'}
    ws = websocket.create_connection(websocketURL)
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))
    res = ws.recv()
    ws.close()
    print res

    frameId = json.loads(res)['result']['frameId']
    print frameId
    geturl = requests.get('http://localhost:9222/json')
    websocketURL = json.loads(geturl.content)[0]['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
    req = {}
    req['id'] = 1
    req['method'] = 'Page.getResourceContent'
    req['params'] = {"frameId":frameId,"url": 'http://global.bing.com'}
    header = ["User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"]
    pdb.set_trace()
    ws = websocket.create_connection(websocketURL,header=header)
    ws.send(json.dumps(req))
    ress = ws.recv()
    ws.close()
    print ress
if __name__ == '__main__':
    send()
```

3.Page.navigate work fine,i got something like this:
{"id":1,"result":{"frameId":"8504.2"}}

4.when i try method:getResourceContent,error came out:
{"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Agent is not enabled."},"id":1}

i tried to add User-Agent,still not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The error message "Agent is not enabled" has nothing to do with the HTTP `User-Agent` header but refers to an agent within chrome that needs to be enabled in order to retrieve page contents.

The term "agent" is a bit misleading since the [protocol documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) speaks about domains which need to be enabled in order to debug them (the term "agent" refers to the way this is implemented in Chrome internally, I suppose)

So, the question is which domain does need to be enabled in order to access the page contents? In hindsight it is quite obvious: the `Page` domain needs to be enabled as we are calling a method in this domain. I only found this out after stumbling over [this example](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Take-page-screenshot), though.

Once I added the `Page.enable` request to script to activate the `Page` domain, the error message disappeared. However, I encountered two other problems:

1. The websockets connection needs to be kept open between requests as Chrome  keeps some state between invocations (such as whether the agent is enabled)
2. When navigating to *http://global.bing.com/* the browser is redirected to *http://www.bing.com/* (at least it is on my computer). This causes `Page.getResourceContent` to fail to retrieve the resource because the requested resource *http://global.bing.com/* is not available.

After fixing these issues I was able to retrieve the page content. This is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8
"""
chrome --remote-debugging api test
"""

import json
import requests
import websocket

def send():
    # Setup websocket connection:
    geturl = requests.get('http://localhost:9222/json')
    websocketURL = json.loads(geturl.content)[0]['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
    ws = websocket.create_connection(websocketURL)

    # Navigate to global.bing.com:
    request = {}
    request['id'] = 1
    request['method'] = 'Page.navigate'
    request['params'] = {"url": 'http://global.bing.com'}
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))
    result = ws.recv()
    print "Page.navigate: ", result
    frameId = json.loads(result)['result']['frameId']

    # Enable page agent:
    request = {}
    request['id'] = 1
    request['method'] = 'Page.enable'
    request['params'] = {}
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))
    print 'Page.enable: ', ws.recv()

    # Retrieve resource contents:
    request = {}
    request['id'] = 1
    request['method'] = 'Page.getResourceContent'
    request['params'] = {"frameId": frameId, "url": 'http://www.bing.com'}
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))
    result = ws.recv()
    print("Page.getResourceContent: ", result)

    # Close websocket connection
    ws.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send()
```

Comment: This will be much easier when you use a Python Devtools API client like [PyChrome](https://github.com/fate0/pychrome)